# express js angular js update from mysql and Angular Js modules

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js

1. I am new to Angular and I try to lern it. 
   I have problems with update a user. I click to the button but nothing happend.
   Backand is ok, with rest client in firefox.

The second problem is that I can not put another module to the Angular app.
When I do this my app show a blank page without errors. I have only ngRoute as a Angular module.

My code:

Part of Html

```
     <!-- Modal Edit Customer -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="edit" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Kunde</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" maxlength="70" ng-model="cust"> 


            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button  class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" ng-click="updateCustomer()" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>

        </div>  
    </div>
```

Part of the controller

```
    //update Customer
    updateCustomer();
    $scope.updateCustomer = updateCustomer;
    function updateCustomer() {

$http.post('/customers/update' , {

            "name" : $scope.name
        }) 
        .then(function successCallback(data, status, headers, config) {

           $('#edit').modal('hide');

           $scope.clearCustomerForm();

           $scope.getAll();


        console.log(data, status, headers, config);



   },

     function errorCallback(error, data) {
         console.log('Error Updating: ' + data);

        })


     };
```

routers.js file - This is the problem with the blank page, see above

```
var app = angular.module('appCheck', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        controller  : "customersCTRL",
        templateUrl : "/app/customers/customers.html"
    })

    .when("/customers", {
        controller  : "customersCTRL",
        templateUrl : "/app/customers/customers.html"
    })
    .when("/lists", {
        controller  : "listsCTRL",
        templateUrl : "/app/lists/lists.html"
    })
    .when("/items", {
        controller  : "itemsCTRL",
        templateUrl : "/app/items/items.html"
    })
    .when("/activities", {
        controller  : "activityCTRL",
        templateUrl : "/app/activities/activities.html"

    })
    .when("/details", {
        controller  : "detailCTRL",
        templateUrl : "/app/details/details.html"

    })

    .when("/singlecustomer", {
        controller  : "singleCustomerCTRL",
        templateUrl : "/app/customers/singleC.html"

    })
    .otherwise({
              redirectTo: '/'
    });

    // use the HTML5. Disable for old browsers that do not support HTML5 
    // With HTML5(false) shoud use #! to the href in the index.html
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
   $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
});
```

Please explain the answer, I am new to Angular. Thank you

Comment: I have solved the second problem with an Array in routers.js before function: ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function

Comment: I think your callback should be changed to `.then(function successCallback(res)` so you can pull out your data from it with `res.data`

Comment: Sorry, but nothing happend